# Divide and Conquer array summation or Loop based array Summation?

Tags: python, divide-and-conquer

I tried to sum an array using this two Algorithms:

- The Divide and Conquer based
- The Naive Loop based Algorithm

Here is the code:

```
# Summation divide and conquer
def summation(array,left,right):
   if left == right:
       return array[left]
   else:
       if left == right-1:
           return array[left] + array[right]
       else:
           mid  = left + (right-left)//2
           left_hand = summation(array,left,mid)
           right_hand = summation(array,mid+1,right)
           return left_hand + right_hand
```

And..

```
# Loop summation
def summation_normal(array):
   sums = 0
   for i in range(len(array)):
       sums += array[i]
   return sums
```

Both of the above algorithms are working correctly and asymptotically both are O(n).

But I am not able to Identify whether which one of them is faster. 
Please help

Comment: You want to do speed testing? Then just repeat the same code 10000 times and time measure it.

Comment: I tried that using the %timeit. But I want to know the reason behind one being faster than other.

Comment: But, you say you are not able to identify which one is faster... so what are you trying to say now? Did you find out which one is faster?

Comment: Sir , somewhere I read Divide and Conquer Algo is Faster , but when I tried %timeit, The result was quite opposite. I just want to understand why there is such difference in the above two algorithms.

Comment: Count the number of times an addition is performed that involves the array. You'll find that that number is always the same for both algorithms. The recursive algorithm just has more overhead.

Comment: @Roosh, "somewhere I read Divide and Conquer Algorithm is faster".  Since both are `O(n)` for the summation task, the exact runtime will be incredibly implementation dependent.  Moreso for python, because it abstracts so much away from the programmer.

Comment: Also, recursion is almost never faster than an equivalent loop-based implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of additions performed on array values is (almost!) the same in both algorithms, but the recursive one has more overhead, so it will run slightly slower.

You can visualise the recursive algorithm going through a binary tree, taking the values of two child nodes and summing them into their parent node. So the number of additions (of array values) corresponds to the number of inner nodes of that tree.

Now look at a short array of 2 elements (with indexes 0 and 1):

```
       +
      / \
     0   1
```

The plus represents the only addition that happens in the recursive algorithm. Now visualise that one element is added to the array. This means one of the leaf-nodes becomes a parent of two leaf nodes (one leaf node is added). For example:

```
       +
      / \
     +   2
    / \
   0   1
```

So now one more addition needs to be performed: there is one more inner node. You can easily see that adding another array element in this structure increases the number of inner nodes with 1. So there will be one more addition.

Again, in the tree representation, the leaf nodes represent the array values and the inner nodes represent the intermediate sums that are made.

The number of leaves in a binary tree is always one more than the number of inner nodes. And so the number of additions involving array values is n-1. This is one less than the iterative solution, because there the first (and extra) addition is `0 + array[0]`. You could improve that by starting with `array[0]` and start your loop at index 1. If you do that, both algorithms will perform n-1 additions involving array values.

Obviously the recursive algorithm has more "housekeeping" to do: calculating the middle index, using the stack for passing arguments, ...etc, so it will be a bit slower, but not with a different time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

```
a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000)
%timeit summation(a, 0, len(a)-1)
3.59 ms ± 81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Output:

```
%timeit summation_normal(a)
1.29 ms ± 7.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Please do keep in mind these timings depend a lot on the activities going on in your processor and several other factors.

Clearly summation_normal is the winner here.